# Angular 2 : Google Docs Viewer

Tags: angular, google-api, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

I want view my documents inside a browser. I was refering one github article for which i found once url to be formed

https://docs.google.com/a/[DOMINIO]/viewer?url=[FILE_URL]

not able to understand what does DOMINIO means?

https://gist.github.com/izazueta/4961650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of the GitHub link you provided is probably using his native language here (which I presume is Spanish), so [DOMINIO is DOMAIN in English](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/dominio). And from the same link:

> **kingsleyudenewu**:
>
> Hi please the google doc FIle viewer https://docs.google.com/a/[DOMINIO]/viewer?url=[FILE_URL] what do i replace the DOMINIO with.
>
> ---
>
> **SeasDev**:
>
> Kingsley you replace the [DOMINIO] with the site's domain name like this
>   [FILE_URL] = http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/einstein-albert.pdf
>   [DOMINIO] = nasonline
>
> https://docs.google.com/a/nasonline/viewer?url=http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/einstein-albert.pdf